# Can anyone explain what this symbol means?

Tags: translation, meaning, usage, characters, character-identification

Please translate this Chinese character symbol found on Chinese food bowl.

[image]

Comment: 食 ..............

Answer (score 0):

食 - Direct translation is “food.” (Aka 食物)
In context (on a food bowl) can mean “eat.” (食用)

Comment: Suspected it had something to do with food - didnt think it would be so obvious. Have had these bowls for years & was always curious. Many Thanks .

Comment: A contextless single character 食 means *to eat*, not *food*. 食物, 食品 means the *things* 物, 品 that are *eaten* 食.

Comment: Well, for the sack of  discussion, since as a noun 食 means "food" and as a verb, "to eat", and since it is written on, most likely, a rice or serving bowl, then probably the bowl is meant for containing "food", and not some other unmentionables, a kind of " Victual X marks the Spot"  :)

Comment: Interesting. We originally hoped that it meant "enjoy" or "delicious". We had a laugh when we learned that it meant "Food" or "to eat". Our thinking was "Food" as opposed to ?? (Possibly something unmentionable).  Many thanks to all for identification & clarification.